# How to find FILE_KEY in Parse?

Tags: database, file, parse-platform, migration, key

I am migrating parse to other backend providers

There I come across the FILE_KEY requirement 
So where can I get FILE_KEY parameter?

I checked in settings/Keys Section but I couldn't find the file key.
I also checked in Cloud section of parse's Dashboard but I could not find it over there also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update parse dashboard and then follow this link
http://docs.back4app.com/docs/parse-migration/parse-apps-keys/

I solve my issue using this because old parse dashboard not showing file_key.

Hope this will help to you too.